# Do Sri Lankans need a transit visa for a 14-hour layover in Abu Dhabi?

Tags: transit-visas, sri-lankan-citizens, abu-dhabi

I'm travelling from the USA to Sri Lanka via Abu Dhabi. I hold a Sri Lankan passport and I have a layover in Abu Dhabi for 14 hours and 30 minutes. I'm planning to remain inside the airport. Do I need to apply for a transit visa?

Comment: What will you do for 14.5 hours at the airport? Might as well get a transit visa and roam around the city

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no visa requirements for airside transit in Abu Dhabi. Have a safe trip.